# Qt: How to generate executable with debug info?

Tags: qt, debugging

When I run `qmake -project`, `qmake`, `make`, `gdb my_executable` I cant debug it because it has not debug info. I need something like `g++ -g` option. How to create executable with debug info?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`qmake` then `qmake CONFIG+=debug` and `make`. To get a binary with debiging symbols.